# How can i convert text type input to number?

Tags: angularjs

I was confused with filter.

We can use filter attributes as `{{ num | number }}`

why can't we use like this?

```
<input type="text" name="name" ng-model="num" />
<input type="number" name="name" ng-model="num | number" />
```

If my approach is wrong. How can i convert **text type input** to **number**?

Comment: Filters are for rendering, not changing the data.

Comment: @venkat filters can be used with ng-repeat and not with ng-model

Comment: What do you means by "**convert text type input to number**", you would like to force typing **only** numbers in your input?

Comment: convert <input type="text" /> to <input type="number"/> @Mistalis

Comment: `<input type="number">` is enough, putting letters in this input will not apply to the model.

Answer (score 0):

you can not use filter in ng-model because ng-model is two way binding and filter allows only output so if filter is used then ng-model can not bind the new value so you have to call filter in your controller when text value changes for ex. something like below

```
<input type="text" name="name" ng-model="num" />
<input type="number" name="name" ng-model="numFormatted" />
```

consider ng-model is different for both inputs and numFormatted will be manipulated in the controller with filter

in your controller

```
function yourController($scope,$filter)
{
  $scope.$watch('num', function(newValue) {
     $scope.numFormatted = $filter('number')(newValue); // here we convert changed value of num to number using filter
  });

  $scope.num = "1";
}
```

so now whenever num model is changed using input type="text" it will convert it to number and assign to numFormatted so type="number" will be updated.